Enum Item Orientation
How can the enum item orientation be controlled? For me it's horizontally oriented but I saw it for others being vertically. Is there a setting in the preferences to this I just haven't found yet or how else? Example images below, thanks in advance!



How did you invoke this menu? I can't find it. And what Blender version?

It's an addon of mine, and the menu is an enum property. It has always appeared horizontally to me, as shown in the first image, but I noticed that for others, it is displayed vertically, as in the second image. Do you think this might be code-related rather than something in the preferences?
